# Remove " add to cart " button for ordered product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to remove `add to cart` button from ordered products, products that user has placed order. Like, When user checkout with 1 or multiple products, when he'll place his order then remove `add to cart` button from that ordered products only, button should remove temporary not permanent. Because I have added new field in checkout page named `Date Of Event`.

It should work like this: if user will select date `7/4/2019 or 9/4/2019` during checkout in checkout page and will place his order, then `add to cart` button will remove from ordered products only for that day which user has selected date in `Date Of Event Field` during checkout.

I am trying to remove add to cart button from ordered products, but see what I have tried, It's removing add to cart button from all products even these products are not ordered.

Please help.

Added custom field code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'date_of_event_field');

function date_of_event_field($checkout){

    echo '<div id="date_of_event_field" class="margin-top-20">';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'date_of_event', array(
            'type'          => 'date',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Date Of Event'),
            'required'      => true,
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'date_of_event' ));

    echo '</div>';

}
```

Trying to remove add to cart button from ordered products but it's removing button from all products:

```
function hidecart() {
    $found = has_bought_items();
    if (!empty($found)) {
        $event_date = $_POST['date_of_event'];
        if ($found === $event_date) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'hidecart', 10, 1);

function has_bought_items() {
    $bought = false;
    $event_date = $_POST['date_of_event'];
    //get product id if single or for shop page u will have to retrieve in some other way
    $product_id = get_the_ID();

    $customer_orders = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value' => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type' => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed' // Only orders with status "completed"
            ));
    foreach ($customer_orders as $customer_order) {
        // Updated compatibility with WooCommerce 3+
        $order_id = method_exists($order, 'get_id') ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;
        $order = wc_get_order($customer_order);

        // Iterating through each current customer products bought in the order
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
            // WC 3+ compatibility
            if (version_compare(WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<'))
                $order_product_id = $item['product_id'];
            else
                $order_product_id = $item->get_product_id();

            // Your condition related to your 2 specific products Ids
            if ($product_id == $product_id) {
                $bought = true;
                $event_date = $_POST['date_of_event'];
                // you can fetch your event date stored as order meta
                return $event_date;
            }
        }
    }
    return $event_date;
}
```

Can someone please help?

I am stuck.